# html5 player api with multiple sources

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

i find this script

script:

```
var vid = document.getElementById('video');
vid.controls = true;

var source = document.createElement('source');
source.setAttribute('src', 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B_4b_1HlxqypYmlncHBEUE03aU0/%5Bhttp:%2F%2Fan1me.info%5D%20Gintama%20001');
vid.appendChild(source);
```

html: `<video id="video">
        <script src="video.js"></script>
     </video>`

but i want to make something like that

```
var vid = document.getElementById('video');
vid.controls = true;

var source = document.createElement('source');
source[1].setAttribute('src', 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B_4b_1HlxqypYmlncHBEUE03aU0/%5Bhttp:%2F%2Fan1me.info%5D%20Gintama%20001');
source[2].setAttribute('src', 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B_4b_1HlxqypYmlncHBEUE03aU0/%5Bhttp:%2F%2Fan1me.info%5D%20Gintama%20002');
source[3].setAttribute('src', 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B_4b_1HlxqypYmlncHBEUE03aU0/%5Bhttp:%2F%2Fan1me.info%5D%20Gintama%20003');
source[4].setAttribute('src', 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B_4b_1HlxqypYmlncHBEUE03aU0/%5Bhttp:%2F%2Fan1me.info%5D%20Gintama%20004');
vid.appendChild(source);
```

and in html to show one from the source(no play list)

```
<video id="video"> 
<script id="1" src="video.js"></script> 
</video>
```

and for video two id"2" and all videos like this?